# Docker Node.js with nginx

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, npm, dockerfile

i try to dockerzied `node.js , pm2`

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17.0 AS build

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install PM2 globally
RUN npm install --global pm2
RUN cd /usr/app && ls
# Credential for real time monitoring PM2 Plus
ENV PM2_PUBLIC_KEY xxxxx
ENV PM2_SECRET_KEY xxxxx


# Copy "package.json" and "package-lock.json" before other files
# Utilise Docker cache to save re-installing dependencies if unchanged
COPY ./package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy all files
COPY ./ ./

# Build app
RUN npm run-script build

# Expose the listening port
EXPOSE 3000

# Launch app with PM2
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]


FROM nginx:alpine

# ## Replace the default nginx index page with our Angular app
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
RUN ls
COPY --from=build  /usr/app /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

it's working without nginx and run succesfuly , but when i try to proxy_pass there is error.

nginx

```
# Run as a less privileged user for security reasons.
user nginx;

# #worker_threads to run;
# "auto" sets it to the #CPU_cores available in the system, and
# offers the best performance.
worker_processes    auto;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        # Hide nginx version information.
        server_tokens off;

        listen  80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
             #   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        gzip            on;
        gzip_vary       on;
        gzip_http_version  1.0;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        gzip_types
                        application/atom+xml
                        application/javascript
                        application/json
                        application/rss+xml
                        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
                        application/x-font-ttf
                        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
                        application/xhtml+xml
                        application/xml
                        font/opentype
                        image/svg+xml
                        image/x-icon
                        text/css
                        text/plain
                        text/x-component;
        gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gunzip          on;
    }
}
```

when i add nginx conf and run

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 test/test
```

there is error 502.
what is my problem ? why it's not working proxy_pass. without proxy_pass working fine , in 3000 port
what is my problem ? why it's not working proxy_pass. without proxy_pass working fine , in 3000 port

Answer (score 2):

A Dockerfile only builds one image, usually out of the very last build stage (starting from the final `FROM` line).  So in your case the image that's being built *only* contains the Nginx server and the compiled front-end application.  It does not contain the separate Node server and nothing inside the container is listening on port 3000.

I'd suggest one of two possible approaches here.

If your application is something like a React or Angular pure front-end application, leave this setup as-is.  The first stage will never be run *per se* so you don't need a `CMD` in it.  Remove the `proxy_pass` Nginx configuration option (and maybe the entire custom Nginx configuration) and just serve the static files.

On the other hand, if your application is more of an Express back-end service, then you need to run this as two separate containers.  This is a more involved process:

First, split this Dockerfile into two.  I might have the `Dockerfile` be just the back-end application (I might remove the unnecessary `pm2` setup, and definitely do not leak credentials via Dockerfile `ENV`).  A second `Dockerfile.nginx` would copy the static assets from the first image; I might simplify the Dockerfile slightly

```bash
# Dockerfile.nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=my-name/my-app /usr/app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

(So long as the built application includes an `index.html` it will overwrite the default contents; the base image's `CMD` is inherited and you don't need to restate it.)

In the Nginx configuration set `proxy_pass http://backend:3000/;`  Keep a `try_files` line too, or add separate routes for a `/static` or `/assets` path, if those files are in the image.

Finally, write a Docker Compose setup to start the two containers together:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend: # <-- this name matches proxy_pass
    build: .
    image: my-name/my-app # <-- this name matches COPY --from=
    # ports: ['3000:3000']  # optional
  proxy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

You need to build the image in two steps; first build the back-end image and then build the proxy image.  Compose doesn't have any native way to understand that one of the images depends on the other's content.

```bash
docker-compose build backend
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Compose [automatically creates a network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) so the two containers can talk to each other using their service names `backend` and `proxy` as host names.  (You will see many examples that manually configure `networks:` and `container_name:` but these options are not necessary.)  You can connect to the built application on `http://localhost:8080`; in the Compose `ports:` option the first port number matches the port number in the URL, and the second matches the Nginx `listen` directive (the port inside the container where the server is running).  I've commented out a second `ports:` line which would allow you to directly reach the back-end service bypassing the proxy, if you'd find that useful.